# Uploading file to server doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, file-upload, xamarin, server

I have the following code here:

```
string imgPath = GetPathToImage(uri);
int imageHeight = 250;
int imageWidth = 200;
var bitmap = imgPath.LoadAndResizeBitmap2(imageWidth, imageHeight);
UploadBitmapAsync(bitmap);

async void UploadBitmapAsync(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        const string UPLOAD_IMAGE = "http://" + HostAddress.Main + "/fsrservice/atxm";
        byte[] bitmapData;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, stream);
        bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(bitmapData);

        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "file",
            FileName = "my_uploaded_image.jpg"
        };

        string boundary = "---8d0f01e6b3b5dafaaadaad";
        MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
        multipartContent.Add(fileContent);
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(UPLOAD_IMAGE, multipartContent);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS! " + content);
            bitmap.Recycle();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT SUCCESSFUL!");
        }
    }
```

It doesn't give any error (gives the `NOT SUCCESSFUL`) whatsoever but the image won't upload to the server. I am using Xamarin Android for this and I based my code here: [Upload Bitmap Image Using HTTP Multipart in Xamarin Android](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/xamarin/upload-bitmap-image-to-server-using-http-multipart-in-xamarin-android). `fsrservice` is a web service I use for my app and this is where I put the folder `atxm` where I save the files. What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Okay so I'm still trying to figure this out and then I stumbled upon this method, [WebClient.UploadData Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktfa4fek(v=vs.110).aspx). I added this to my web service and created an .aspx but I cannot see the uploaded file to the folder. From client, the file was passed through byte array.

Here are my codes:

Service1.svc.cs

```
public string FileUpload(EmployeeDetails userInfo)
    {
        Database context = new Database();
        List<byte[]> byteArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<byte[]>>(userInfo.File);
        List<string> fileName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(userInfo.FileName);
        List<string> editedName = new List<string>();

        Attachment obj = new Attachment();

        for (int i = 1; i <= byteArray.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < fileName.Count; j++)
            {
                // SOME CODE HERE
            }
        }

        context.SubmitChanges();

        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Count; i++)
        {
            byte[] b = byteArray[i];
            string uriString = "http://" + HostAddress.Address + "/FSRService/upload.aspx";
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myWebClient.UploadData(uriString, "POST", b);
        }

        string msg = null;
        return msg;          
    }
```

upload.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="WcfService.upload" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web"%>

<Script language="C#" runat=server>
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\FSRService\\ATXM\\" + file.FileName);
    }   
}

</Script>
<html>
<body>
<p> Upload complete.  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

1. How do I edit/add the filename for the file I am going to upload?
2. Why does the file not uploaded to the folder?

Comment: Are you trying to upload camera pictures?

Comment: @Mulflar No, photos from gallery.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try your code and see

Comment: @Mulflar Thank you! I've been trying to solve this for almost a day but I still can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Is the server receiving the request?  Does it get all of the data?

Comment: Are you trying to upload the files directly to a folder? As I see Multipart works to send multiple parts of a big image to a webservice who is expecting and image, not to a folder.

Comment: @Jason I have another method for downloading files from that folder which works, so I think it is communicating to and from the server.

Comment: @Mulflar Yes. Is that not allowed? How should I expect it to receive different file types like image, ppt, excel, pdf, etc.?

Comment: It seems your problem looks like you are pointing to a folder, not to a webservice.
Also as I see in your code you are not splitting the file. If the file is small enough to not need any split you cand think not to use Multipart.
You cand send it as a bit array to a webservice who reconstructs the array into the file kind (I can give you the code for this if you want).
Also you told us you are downloading files from the server, ¿are you using a webservice or FTP?

Comment: I see. For the downloading, I am using httpclient and I just use the http url. I think that's the reason why it works because it gets a particular file.

Comment: @Mulflar Hi, I am still unable to upload the files to the server. I changed the method I'm using but it still doesn't appear in the folder. Could you help me? Pls see the edit above.

Comment: @Jason Hi, please see the edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok
What I donne is something like this.

First of all i use a object for the file like this:

```
class FileTransfer
{
    public byte[] content;
    public string name;

    public FileTransfer(string name, byte[] content)
    {
        this.name= name;
        this.content= content;
    }
}
```

Then I have a webservice in Asp.Net who looks like:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string GetFile(string data)//the file comes serialized to Json
 {
      //Transforms the string into the object
      FileTransfer recived = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FileTransfer>(data);
      string path = "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\FSRService\\ATXM\\"+recived.name; //you could also do this in the object builder
      File.WriteAllBytes(path, recived.content);
 }
```

Now in Xamarin you can directly add your .asmx webservice as a webreference by right click on your project, add, add web reference and it will create a "class" with the async functions.

And you can use it like this:

```
public void SendFile(File fileToSend)
{
      //process the file
      FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(fileToSend.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      int len = (int)objfilestream.Length;
      Byte[] documentcontents = new Byte[len];
      objfilestream.Read(documentcontents, 0, len);
      objfilestream.Close();
      FileTransfer newFiletoSend = new FileTransfer(file.Name, documentcontents);
      string raw = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(newFiletoSend); 

      //send it
      nameOfTheWebServiceClass.nameOfTheAsmxFile service = new nameOfTheWebServiceClass.nameOfTheAsmxFile();
      service.GetFile(raw); //GetFile is the name of the funcion you want to use in the .asmx webservice.
 }
```

Comment: I literally just added this: `string path = "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\FSRService\\ATXM\\" + editedName[i]; File.WriteAllBytes(path, b);` then BOOM it worked! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Nice. I'm happy you get the solution ^_^